# How does a method with multiple parameters get passed to a Function that takes a List?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am not able to understand how the function gets passed via a lambda into this method

```
public class OrderUtil {
 public static <I, O> List<O> runInBatches(List<I> inputList, 
 Function<List<I>, List<O>> functionToRunInBatches) {
    return Lists.partition(inputList, BATCH_CHUNK_SIZE).stream()
            .flatMap(batch -> functionToRunInBatches.apply(batch).stream())
            .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

I see the below code, I am not able to understand how the lambda function below translates to functionToRunInBatches above? orderDao.getOrderForDates(...) takes three parameters (orders, startdate, enddate) but my function takes a list and returns a list. How does this call work fine?

I have read the tutorials and documentation on Function.

**Would it be possible for someone to break down how the lambda gets mapped to the Function above? I am unable to visualise how this ends up working.**

```
 private List<Order> getOrderForDates(List<Long> orderNumbers, 
                                           tring startDate, String endDate){
    return OrderUtil.runInBatches(orderNumbers,
            orderBatch -> orderDAO.getOrderForDates(orderBatch, startDate, endDate));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda is turned into a new `Function` object by the compiler. It overrides the `apply` method with the code given in the lambda expression.

So this:

```
private List<Order> getOrderForDates(List<Long> orderNumbers, String startDate, String endDate){
    return OrderUtil.runInBatches(orderNumbers, orderBatch -> orderDAO.getOrderForDates(orderBatch, startDate, endDate));
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
private List<Order> getOrderForDates(List<Long> orderNumbers, String startDate, String endDate){
    return OrderUtil.runInBatches(orderNumbers, new Function<List<Long>, List<Order>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Order> apply(List<Long> orderBatch) {
            return orderDAO.getOrderForDates(orderBatch, startDate, endDate);
        }
    });
}
```

Your `runInBatches` method then simply calls `apply` on that `Function` object.

Comment: to easier understand this, you could say `alike`, but these are *not* equivalent

Comment: @Eugene My English might escape me here, but my dictionary lists "alike" and "equivalent" as synonyms. Care to elaborate the distinction?

Comment: interesting, Im not a native english speaker myself, but somehow found these being similar, but different. Anyway, from the top of my head : You can override equals and hashCode for AIC, not for lambdas. AIC can be created from a class or interface with multiple methods, lambdas cant. AIC can carry additional state, lambdas cant. "this" is changed for a lambda vs AIC.

Comment: I specifically used "equivalent" because they are not "equal". "Alike" feels to me to carry the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This lambda expression:

```
orderBatch -> orderDAO.getOrderForDates(orderBatch, startDate, endDate)
```

can be *targeted* to the `Function<List<Long>, List<Order>>` *functional interface* because:

- It receives a `List<Long>` argument, which is named `orderBatch`, at the left of the `->` operator
- It returns a `List<Order>`, because the `orderDAO.getOrderForDates` method returns a `List<Order>`
- `Function` is a *functional interface*, meaning that it declares only one abstract method, in this case `apply`

Here the number of arguments of the `orderDAO.getOrderForDates` method doesn't have any importance. What matters is the number and types of the arguments of the lambda expression (only one, which is `orderBatch` of type `List<Long>`) and the number and types of the arguments of the targeted functional interface's **unique abstract method**, in this case the `apply` method of the `Function` interface.

On the other side, `startDate` and `endDate` are *captured* by the lambda expression and are also known as *free variables*, meaning that they aren't arguments of the function (they are neither arguments of the `Function.apply` method nor arguments of the lambda expression, as they are not declared at the left side of the `->` operator). They aren't variables local to the function either, as they aren't declared inside the lambda expression. In other words, they come from outside of the function without being arguments of it.